Conversion failed: "(-122.763091,49.04676)" to geography (location)
I am trying to import a CSV file into PostgreSQL with a column named location that contains coordinates in the format (-longitude,latitude). However, I am getting the following error:
2:36846: conversion failed: "(-122.763091,49.04676)" to geography (location)
3:37257: conversion failed: "(-123.141289,49.272057)" to geography (location)
4:36495: conversion failed: "(-122.850334,49.189992)" to geography (location)

I have checked the following:

The SRID is set to 4326.
The values in the location column are in the correct format (-longitude,latitude).
There are no invalid or incomplete values in the location column.

I am using PostgreSQL 14 and PostGIS 3.2.
Example:
The following is an example of the data in my CSV file:
-122.763091,49.04676
-123.141289,49.272057
-122.850334,49.189992

What am I doing wrong?

Where is your code?

@scrappedcola
I do not use any code. I tried to import via JetBrains database tools  also pgAdmin

@AhmadBadpey Edit the question to describe your process and the tools you're using, possibly adding the missing tags as well.

If this example resembles how you keep those geographies in the CSV file:
id,description,geog
1,"description1","(-122.850334,49.189992)"

Then reading the third field to geography type column won't work because that's not a valid geography constant. None of these would work either:
id,description,geog
1,"description1","(-122.850334 49.189992)"
1,"description1","-122.850334,49.189992"
1,"description1","-122.850334 49.189992"

This would:
id,description,geog
1,"description1","point(-122.850334 49.189992)"

You could change your column to text, import it as is, prepend the point, swap out the comma , for a space  , then alter the type back to geography(point,4326). Demo at db<>fiddle:
create table my_table (id int, description text, geog geography(Point,4326));
--preparing a test file:
copy (select '1,"abc","(-122.850334,49.189992)"') to '/tmp/my_file.csv';

alter table my_table 
  alter column geog type text;

copy my_table from '/tmp/my_file.csv' csv delimiter ',' quote '"';

select *,pg_typeof(geog) from my_table;




id
description
geog
pg_typeof




1
abc
(-122.850334,49.189992)
text



update my_table 
  set geog='point'||replace(geog,',',' ')
  returning *,pg_typeof(geog);




id
description
geog
pg_typeof




1
abc
point(-122.850334 49.189992)
text



alter table my_table 
  alter column geog type geography(point,4326) 
  using geog::geography(point,4326);

select *,pg_typeof(geog),st_astext(geog) from my_table;




id
description
geog
pg_typeof
st_astext




1
abc
0101000020E6100000522B4CDF6BB65EC0354069A851984840
geography
POINT(-122.850334 49.189992)




You could also leverage the fact that those values are valid point type constants - that's PostgreSQL built-in point type, not to be confused with PostGIS geometry(point). Postgres point can accept those values directly, and then there' a predefined cast from that to PostGIS geometry(point), and from that to geography(point):
truncate my_table;
copy (select '1,"abc","(-122.850334,49.189992)"') to '/tmp/my_file.csv';
alter table my_table
  drop column if exists geog,
  add column geog point;

copy my_table from '/tmp/my_file.csv' csv delimiter ',' quote '"';

alter table my_table 
  alter column geog type geography(point,4326) 
  using geog::geometry(point)::geography(point,4326);


@zegark Thank you very much for taking the time to examine the problem in detail. The solution you gave solved my problem. You are perfect...
